# push message from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

when I use from javascript works perfectly but when I click link button nothing happens. how can I fix pushing message from code behind?

```
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" id="message" />
            <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
            <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
            <ul id="discussion">
            </ul>
        </div>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>


        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

                chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                    // Html encode display name and message. 
                    var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                    var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                    // Add the message to the page. 
                    $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                        + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
                };
                // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
                $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
                // Set initial focus to message input box.  
                $('#message').focus();
                // Start the connection.
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                        // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                        chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                        $('#message').val('').focus();
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>


protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
    context.Clients.All.Send("asf", "111");
}

public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(signalRtest.Startup))]   
namespace signalRtest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Page_Load event with object sender, EventArgs e parameters?

Comment: there is nothing in pageload.

Comment: @Mert, can you provide _full_ html?

Comment: there is nothing else, just imagine this is inside of form tag.